# Dynamically changing the glyphicon of input add on

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How to change **glyphicon" (right side of input field (see below)) on validation of input type ?

eg. When input **is valid**, change it to **glyphicon-ok** (tick mark ) or when it is invalid change it to **glyphicon-remove** ( cross sign )

[image]

```
vm.rentalFields = [
    {
        key: 'first_name',
        type: 'input',
     //   class:glyphicon-ok,

        templateOptions: {

            type: 'text',
            label: 'First Name',
            placeholder: 'Enter your first name',

            required: true,
            "addonRight": {
                "class": "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"
              }




        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With angular-formly, if you want anything to be dynamic, you use [`expressionProperties`](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.13.0/docs/learn-angular-formly#section--expression-properties-https-egghead-io-lessons-angularjs-angular-formly-expressionproperties-pl-7-). Because you want the `class` property of `addonRight` to be dynamic, your `expressionProperties` property for that will be:

```
'templateOptions.addonRight.class': '"glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-" + (fc.$valid ? "ok" : "remove")'
```

The values of `expressionProperties` are called [formly expressions](http://docs.angular-formly.com/v6.13.0/docs/formly-expressions) which basically means they can be strings which are evaluated on the `formly-field`'s `$scope` or a function that is passed `($viewValue, $modelValue, scope)` and can return the value or a promise that resolves to the value.

The `fc` you see in that expression is a shortcut for `options.formControl` which is assigned to your field's [`NgModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) (which is why you have access to `$valid`.

At the end of the day, your field config will look something like this:

```
vm.rentalFields = [
  {
    key: 'first_name',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      type: 'text',
      label: 'First Name',
      placeholder: 'Enter your first name',
      required: true,
      addonRight: {
        class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback' // <-- initialized to a valid state
      }
    },
    expressionProperties: {
      'templateOptions.addonRight.class': '"glyphicon form-control-feedback glyphicon-" + (fc.$valid ? "ok" : "remove")'
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ng-class on the container that stores the glyphicon, and then conditional check a variable that stores the validity of the input. For example this is the approach using forms:

```
    <form class="form-inline" name="myForm">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" ng-maxlength="5" /> 
       <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': myForm.firstName.$valid, 'glyphicon-remove': myForm.firstName.$invalid}"></span> 
    </form>
```

Where  myForm.firstName.$invalid is the condition on which you set glyphicon. 
(Which is set by the ng-maxlength directive on the input, see this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

Alternatively you can use a separated variable to store the validity of the input based on some rules you figure out in your controller.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14198/

Comment: @TheBeacon is using angular-formly with the angular-formly-templates-bootstrap library which abstracts away the template in favor of reusability and simplicity. So, while you *can* create your own custom field types and have total control over the template, there's an even easier way to customize it and still use angular-formly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

`<span class="glyphicon green" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': {{single_request.status}}==1, 'glyphicon-remove': {{single_request.status}}==0 }" ></span>`